# Parse PHP Array To Build Query String

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to build a multi select on my php page where a user can select what fields to query from a database.  I have the multi-select set-up and I am trying to work on the "behind-the-scenese" syntax for the query build portion, but when I hit my `echo` statement, it is not displaying what is selected.

What would be the proper way to build out a query string based off what is selected from the multi-select on the page?  (Now granted I am omitting a valid connection string etc.)

```
<html>
<select name="employee_data[]" multiple style="min-width: 200px;" id="user_data">
<option value="EmployeeName">Employee Name</option>
<option value="TeamName">Team Name</option>
<option value="ManagerName">Manager Name</option>
<option value="Department">Department</option>
<option value="Recruiter">Recruiter</option>
<option value="RecruitingAgency">RecrutingAgency</option>
</select>
</html>
<?php
  $query = "Select employeename ";
  if (in_array('TeamName')) $query .= ",teamname"
  if (in_array('ManagerName')) $query .= ",ManagerName"
  if (in_array('Department')) $query .= ",Department"
  if (in_array('Recruiter')) $query .= ",Recruiter"
  if (in_array('RecruitingAgency')) $query .= ",RecruitingAgency"
  $query .= " FROM employeepersonelinfo where employeename = '$employeename'";

echo $query;
?>
```

Comment: where's the rest of the code/form ?

Comment: @PedroLobito - what else do I need to show?  Was trying to keep it "to the point" like the guidelines show.

Comment: Why not have them in an array and then implode() it with respect to ','?

Comment: @MilanChheda - can you show an example?

Comment: `$array = ['TeamName', 'ManagerName', 'Department'';
 $query = "SELECT " . implode(',', $array) . " FROM employeepersonelinfo;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MilanChheda - I do not follow.  I am very new to php.

Comment: Sure Smith. I have added code in the answer below. Check it out.

Comment: Since `in_array` has two mandatory parameters, I presume your PHP setup is configured to hide error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the working PHP code. Instead of checking each, you can use `implode()`.

```
<?php
 if (!isset($_POST['employee_data'])) die();
 $query = "Select employeename ";
 $query .= implode(', ', $_POST['employee_data']);
 $query .= " FROM employeepersonelinfo where employeename = '" . 
 $_POST['employeename'] . "'";
 echo $query;
 ?>
```

You don't really need to check each and every value. You can save lines of code and lines of conditions by using array functions.

Comment: The value in `value="Department"` is what should be the field in the query, correct?

Comment: Yes, database table field names, should be your values for the options. Keep them same and you won't have to make any changes in this code.

Comment: I thought they were the same, but just realized I had an `_` in one which is why the syntax was erroring for me.  Thanks again!

Comment: Being able to inject random SQL in the middle of a query opens for very interesting hacking possibilities :)